# Input tag not tied to model , How to access this in controller ? MVC-4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

View :-
I have a view like this .
     `<form action="/NewUser/Register" method="post">
              <input type="text" name="LastName" value=" " />
               <input type="submit" name="btnRegister" value="Register" />
       </form>`

I want to access this in controller . The above view is not tied to model .So, how to do this ?

Comment: Please post your action and view's full code.

Comment: Do you have property named LastName in your view? Is the input posted in a form?

Comment: @AshishCharan I posted my view fully . I am having trouble in accessing this in controller action .

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları No ,view dont have the property as LastName

Comment: @Dhinesh Post the model type.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları This view don't have a specific modal associate with this .

Comment: Then show the controller action you want to post to.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları View is bind to default modal . No specific modal associated with this view . And, In controller I want to manipulate the  user input . I don't know how to get user input in controller .I need help on this part

Comment: There must be some parent controller action which must be rendering a parent view and then this parent view might be having a child view. Please post the action code.

Comment: `public ActionResult index(){ return ResultView(); } public ActionResult Register(){ /*I need to access the LastName text box here*/ retrun ResultView();}`  . There is no parent view associated with is ,not even a layout

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the value in the action method by adding it as a parameter and using HttpPost action filter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(string lastName)
{ 
    return ResultView();
}
```